# Can't wiredly connect to router

Tags: networking, internet, wired

I have a really annoying problem.

Namely, I can't connect to my Ubee evw3226 router through an ethernet cable connection. The wireless works fine. The other computer in my house has a wired connection to the same router and that works just dandy with both Linux and Windows.

I have another internet connection from a different ISP and that connection works both wired and wireless.

I'm lost here, wondering what the problem could be. I'm guessing it's from my system but I have no idea where to look. Oh, on Windows the connection is OK as well, my system being a dual-boot.

Comment: Can you use this Linux machine (the one with the issues) to connect to another router?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this Linux machine (the one with the issues) to connect to another router?  If so, then it sounds like this is the issue:

You are using the wrong configuration for DHCP or static IP (i.e. you need to fix your config, seriously).

Make sure that your router supports DHCP if you're trying to use it.  Make sure that your subnet and gateway addresses are correct.  Also make sure, if you're using a static IP, that you are not trying to claim an address already in use.

If it can't connect to another router, then it sounds like you need drivers.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Yes i can connect to another router wired and wireless just fine it's just the ubee router with witch i have the issue. And no I'm not using a static IP, also my network settings  are default, I had no need to modify anything so far. Another thing I noticed is that when I plug the cable in the daemon it says cable unplugged.

Comment: Have you tried different cables/sockets on router?

Comment: Yes i tried 3 different cables of different lengths including the one that came with the router.  And yes i did try all sockets on the router.

Comment: have you tried using a static IP?  I find many times that that helps.

Comment: Ok so I finally tried the static ip config and still no joy. But I did notice that after I turn off wireless and turn it on again it fails to connect, I have to restat once or twice for it to run again.

Comment: Hm.  No clue at all...

Answer (score 0):

OK so I guess I finally figured out what is the problem. It seems the Ubee router does not support linux I connected another router to it and connected my PC to the second router and it works.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I doubt, that the router even cares about the OS of the connecting device. Ethernet, TCP/IP, DHCP and DNS are all standardized protocols. I suspect something else at work.

Comment: I don't deny. It's just how I fixed the problem.